# Domain redirection and url masking

Tags: url-rewriting, url-routing, redirect

[image: Post preview of facebook]

The image uploaded shows the post preview thumbnail of facebook.

(1)Consider a link **x.com/abc** which is redirected to **y.com/xyz**.

(2)When the link **x.com/abc** is shared on facebook it's preview is fetched from **y.com/xyz**.

(3)The preview thumbnail generated by facebook contains the domain **y.com** and not the **x.com**.

(4)How do we make the preview thumbnail show **x.com** and not the target url **y.com**.

The facebook screenshot show's that I shared url **hivirality.com/abhishek** which is redirected on **citryxsolutions.in** but the preview thumbnail contains the domain name of targeted url i.e **citryxsolutions.in**.

What are the possible cases to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that, but it is a bit tricky. Instead of 301 redirect from  `x.com/abc`  to `y.com/xyz`. Your server should return HTML, which will redirect user through JS. This HTML should have Open Graph markup which Facebook is parsing. For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="URL" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="TITLE" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE URL" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if("false" == "false") {
                window.location = "DESTINATION URL";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where `URL` is `x.com/abc`

And `DESTINATION URL` is `y.com/xyz`

And you can check how Facebook reacts on that in FB debugger (also you can clear cache here): https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/